# Why is underpayment so prevalent? (23% of those who are 25 and are entitled to the UK's National Living Wage are underpaid!)?

Tags: microeconomics, minimum-wage

Context: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/nov/27/one-in-four-uk-workers-covered-national-living-wage-underpaid-low-pay-commission

Why is it that employers can seemingly get away without paying the full NLW? Surely they would be worried that their workers will observe their pay packets and realise that they are illegally underpaying them?

Lastly, a quote from the article above: "The figures from the Low Pay Commission may also include data errors, as well as cover some workers who receive benefits such as accommodation in lieu of pay." Legally, does the NMW have to be purely in monetary terms or can it take other remunerative forms (accommodation subsidies etc).